# Does comparing two pointers do more than to just check their adresses?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, c-strings, memmove

I'm rewriting part of libc, more specifically memmove as an exercise and after being unable to do it myself I looked for its source code and found this (and variations of it):

```
void    *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
  char *d = dest;
  const char *s = src;
  if (d < s)
    while (n--)
      *d++ = *s++;
  else
    {
      char *lasts = s + (n-1);
      char *lastd = d + (n-1);
      while (n--)
        *lastd-- = *lasts--;
    }
  return (dest);
}
```

My question concerns the 5th line `if (d < s)` for me this would only make sense if `d` and `s` contained the size of both `dest` and `src` which as far as my understanding goes is not true. So is this comparison doing anything besides checking the position of the addresses or is my understanding of pointers completely flawed?

Is there any purpose to this code? Sorry in advance if I am completly wrong pointers can be very confusing.

Comment: The pointer does not contain the length of the object it is pointing to. The reason for this check is because the parameters might overlap. To ensure that data from `src` isn't overwritten before it is copied, the algorithm checks if `dest` is to the left or right of `src`. If `dest` is to the left, it starts copying from the left, walking to the right along `src` and `dest`. If it is to the right, it starts copying from the right, walking to the left.

Comment: @LouisCloete are the adresses in the heap or in the stack?

Comment: @MiguelP Doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that the implementation of the library routine uses a comparison that is not defined by the C standard in ordinary user code. The C standard defines `d < s` only if `d` and `s` point into the same array, including the notional position one beyond the last array element. However, the standard library function `memmove` must be able to work even if `d` and `s` point to entirely different objects. This makes it impossible to implement `memmove` with strictly conforming C code; it must rely on the compiler to define `d < s` even when the C standard does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `(uintptr_t)d < (uintptr_t)s` gives a sensible result on most systems, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this comparison doing anything besides checking the position of the addresses?

No. It checks if `d` has a lower address than `s`. If it does, it selects the first strategy, to copy from the beginning of the memory area and forward - otherwise it copies from the end of the memory area backwards

This is to not mess up the result in case `[d,d+n)` and `[s,s+n)` are overlapping.

Example:

```
     +---+---+---+
src  | x | y | z |
     +---+---+---+---+
dest     |   |   |   |
         +---+---+---+
     ^               ^
     |               |
low mem addr    high mem addr
```

Here the second strategy must be chosen. Consider what would happen if the the first strategy is chosen instead:

```
dest[0] = src[0]; // which is x
dest[1] = src[1]; // which is ... x, because the above op overwrote the y
```

Answer (score 3):

The function memmove assumes that the source and destination arrays are overlapped. That is that they are pointers that point to different parts of the same array.
So for example this if statements

```
if (d < s)
```

checks whether the element pointed to by the pointer d precedes the element pointed to by the pointer s in the array.

Consider an example. Let's assume that there is declared an array

```
char s[] = "Hello World!";
```

that is the array contains the string `"Hello World!"`. And you want to change the array such a way that it will contain the string "World!". What you need is to move the part of the source string that contains the substring "World!" to the beginning of the array.

If you will write

```
strcpy( s, s + 6 );
```

then such a call invokes undefined behavior because the function strcpy does not allow to use overlapped subarrays.

Using memmove you may write

```
memmove( s, s + 6, 7 );
```

In this case relative to the provided by you function definition the pointer d has the value of the original array s and the pointer s has the value equal to the expression s + 6.

As the value of d is less than the value of the pointer s then this part of the function gets the control

```
if (d < s)
  while (n--)
    *d++ = *s++;
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 5 When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative
> locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two
> pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point
> one past the last element of the same array object, they compare
> equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate
> object,   pointers to structure members declared later compare
> greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure,
> and **pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare
> greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower
> subscript values.** All pointers to members of the same union object
> compare equal. **If the expression P points to an element of an
> array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the
> same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P.
> In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**

That is from the quote it follows that the two pointers passed to the function memmove shall point to elements of the same array to guarantee the defined behavior for the comparison of the pointers in this if statement

```
if (d < s)
```

Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So it is not for heap/stack control but to allow the user to do pointer arithmetic on the function parameters? What about NUL termination and the rest of the string?

Comment: @MiguelP In this example memmove( s, s + 6, 7 ); the nul terminating character is countered due to using the value equal to 7.

Comment: Re “The function memmove assumes that the source and destination arrays are overlapped.”: No, it assumes they **may** overlap; that is, it works whether the source and the destination are overlapped or not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The comparison using the operator < is valid when pointers point to elements of the same array if they are not members of a structure.

Comment: Re “the two pointers passed to the function memmove shall point to elements of the same array”: This is not true for a standard library implementation of `memmove`. Implementations of standard library routines are not constraint to use strictly conforming C; they can, and sometimes must, rely on behaviors defined by the implementation and not the C standard. In C 2018 7.24.2.2, the standard specifies that `memmove` copies between any two objects. To conform to this specification, it must work whether the objects are subobjects of the same object or are completely unrelated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am referring the C Standard "1 In this International Standard, ‘‘shall’’ is to be interpreted as a requirement on an
implementation or on a program; conversely, ‘‘shall not’’ is to be interpreted as a
prohibition."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: There is no “shall” or “shall not” in the clause that specifies relational operators except for the Constraints section (both operands have real type or both are pointers to versions of compatible types) and the result (“shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false”, which is a specification of what the C implementation does, not a constraint on the program). But it does not matter; implementations of library routines are not required to avoid behavior that is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is enough clear written that in all other cases there is undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: So what if it is undefined behavior? The C standard does not prohibit programs from using behavior it does not define. (It explicitly permits extensions that define behavior it does not define.) When writing the implementation of a standard library function, the implementor is permitted to use behavior that is defined by the C implementation even though it is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are mixing two different notions: unspecified behavior and undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: No, I am not, the statements I have made are specifically about undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A program that has undefined behavior according to the C Standard is not a valid C program. From the C Standard "undefined behavior - behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements"

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course, no one forbids you to write nonportable or erroneous programs. But how am I related with that?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: That quote does not say the program is invalid. It merely says the C standard imposes not requirements. That is fine; the C implementation can impose requirements.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh you are right! An erroneous program is not an invalid program.:) Go ahead!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The quote also does not say this code is erroneous. It applies to behavior upon is of a nonportable **or** erroneous program construct. If the behavior is defined by the C implementation, it is nonportable but not erroneous.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The C Standard clear says that behavior is undefined. And this was written by me in the answer. The question is not about specific implementations that make bugs their features.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: It is a shame; you have fundamentally misunderstood the C standard. It does not define hard limits on what one may not do in C. The C standard is **intended** to be extended. It provides a **start** to the language, a core language that may be extended by C implementations. The standard explicitly tells us that “A conforming language may have extensions.” That is not just grammatical extensions; it includes adding definitions for anything the C standard does not define. C was intended to be adapted for different purposes, not limited to a single rigid specification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, yes you are right. Ha-ha-ha!. As i said nobody prevents you to write nonportable and erroneous programs. What is the problem? As I said go ahead!:)

Comment: I'm confused about whether you meant the restriction on source and destination pointers being within the same object to apply only to a program that  re-implements `memmove` (so does not use `#include <string.h>` at all), or whether you meant it also to apply to a program that uses the `memmove` declared by `#include <string.h>`. The latter is false because the standard does not mention any comparison between the source and destination parameters of `memmove`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I mean that the operator < for pointers is defined when pointers point to elements of the same array. (or for example members of the same structure)  So if the function memmove uses this operator then the function shall not invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you implying that if a function in the C standard library is translated from some C source code, then it cannot make use of undefined aspects of the C language?

Comment: @IanAbbott Code that invokes undefined behavior according to the C Standard is a nonportable and erroneous.

Comment: Nonportable, yes, but the C standard imposes no requirements on what such code can do. It can do what it needs to do in order to implement the required functionality.

Comment: @IanAbbott The operator < for pointers that do not point to elements of the same array has undefined behavior. If you want to write code that has undefined behavior then it is your right   But all qualified programmers will think that you are a beginner that do not know the C Standard.

Comment: C standard library implementations can and do dictate the build environment though, and are not expected to build correctly with every conforming C compiler.

Comment: @IanAbbott Each C program is considered from the point of view whether it satisfies the C Standard.  And if it does not satisfy the C Standard then we are looking for an excuse why it is an invalid program.:) Good luck!:)

Comment: I would consider the implementation of the C standard library as out-of-scope for determining the validity of a strictly conforming C program.